# Does mongoimport version 2.6.7 really have the "--ssl" flag?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

MongoDB's documentation states that `--ssl` is a new feature in version 2.6:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--ssl

However, at the command line I get the following:

```
mongoimport --version
2.6.7
mongoimport --host [ssl-enabled mongodb host] --port 27019 -u [username] -p [pw] --db my_database --collection data --file data.csv --drop --type csv --headerline --ssl
Error parsing command line: unknown option ssl
mongoimport --ssl
Error parsing command line: unknown option ssl
mongoimport --help
// no mention of --ssl in what's returned by "help"
```

What gives? Have I installed some ssl-free version of mongoimport?

Comment: When MongoDB is compiled with SSL support, the switch becomes available. For example in the Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Markus Mahlberg is correct. You must make sure the version of MongoDB you are using is capable and configured for SSL first. Also please post the entire  mongoimport command that you are using including the "source" file and destination db and collection

Comment: If you scroll down slightly further on the manual page you linked to, there's an important note: "Changed in version 3.0: Most MongoDB distributions now include support for SSL.". Prior to MongoDB 3.0, the standard packaged distributions (i.e. 2.6.x) did not include SSL but it was possible to enable by building from source. By default, your standard 2.6.x distribution probably does not include SSL support in either the `mongod` server or command line tools like `mongoimport`.

Comment: Yikes, thanks @Stennie.  Feels like saying "new in 2.6!" is a bit generous -- the MongoDB docs should call that out in the --ssl section.

Comment: I'm not sure what "new in 2.6" is referring to in the docs but it seems to be an error in this context. I think SSL support has been available in the tools as long as it has been included in the server, but the distinction is that SSL has not been included in the standard distributions by default. The "new" here may actually be a misplaced referenced to the 3.0 distributions; will raise a DOCS issue in Jira to get that clarified.

Comment: FYI, raised the documentation clarification as [DOCS-5358](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-5358) in the MongoDB issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Mac and installed mongodb with homebrew it's possible you have to reinstall it using

```
brew install mongodb --with-openssl
```

[installing mongodb 3 on osx](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

[installing mongodb 2.6 on osx](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)